# Access subscription details in Stripe payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I have two subscription plans in my Ruby on Rails application. I use stripe webhook to email to customer when subscription has been created. In the email I want to store data about subscription (and plan) details e.g. when trial_end and plan name or price.

```
def webhook  
 stripe_event = Stripe::Event.retrieve(params[:id]) #retrieving Event ID

    if stripe_event.type == "customer.subscription.created" #checks if retrieved Event type subscription is created 
        stripe_customer_token = stripe_event.data.object.customer # Get Customer ID
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(stripe_customer_token) #here I'm able to retrieve Customer data e.g. customer.email
        subscription = customer.subscriptions.first.id #according to documentation I need to retrieve Subscription by supplying its ID. I can retrieve Subscription, but don't understand how to retrieve its data, like: subscription.trial_end

    UserMailer.customer_subscription_created(customer.email).deliver #this works well
    UserMailer.customer_subscription_created(subscription.trial_end).deliver #this does not work

    end
end
```

I have retrieved Subscription of my Customer. When I retrieve customer I can access my customer data like: customer.email I assumed I would be able to do the same when I retrieve Subscription: subscription.trial_end, but this gives me an error. How can I access Subscription data?

Besides when I change plan of a Subscription I do it like so and it works:

```
 def change_user_plan(customer_id, subscription_id)
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("#{customer_id}")
    subscription = customer.subscriptions.retrieve("#{subscription_id}")
    subscription.plan = 2
    subscription.save
end
```

Here is link to Stripe API to [retrieve Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_subscription)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you are able to do what you are trying to do. Once you have your subscription, `subscription.trial_end` works. I just tested it:

```
2.1.6 :013 > customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("#{customer_id}")                                                                                                           
 => #<Stripe::Customer:0x3fcd1ed0a630 id=...> JSON: { ... } 

2.1.6 :014 > subscription = customer.subscriptions.retrieve("#{subscription_id}")                                                                                                 
 => #<Stripe::Subscription:0x3fcd1ecae574 id=...> JSON: { ... }

2.1.6 :015 > subscription.trial_end
 => 1438387199
```

The problem is this line:

```
subscription = customer.subscriptions.first.id
```

You are saving the subscription id itself. You need to do:

```
subscription = customer.subscriptions.first
```

to save the whole subscription. Also, you can use `subscriptions.retrieve` to supply the id for retrieval (as you are doing in your second code example).